# How does the Shapiro–Wilk test for normality work?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normality-assumption

Can someone explain to me the mechanics of the Shapiro–Wilk test for normality?

I have that: $$W = \frac{ \sum (x_{(j)}-\bar{x})(m_{(j)}-\bar{m})}{\sum (x_{j}-\bar{x})^{2} \sum m_{j}^2}\,\,,$$ where $m_{j}$ is the expected value of the $j$th  order statistic from $N(0,1)$.

So, what is $x_{j}$ here? Is the $m_{j}$ from a theoretical distribution, or from an observed sample? What is the test statistic comparing?

Comment: Note it's "Shapiro-Wilk test" - there's confusion between the two statisticians [Samuel S. Wilks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_S._Wilks) and [Martin Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Wilk), but it was the latter involved in the Shapiro-Wilk test. (No doubt the confusion is increased by the English use of possessive "'s").

Answer (score 3):

It's basically a sample correlation between empirical quantile and quantile from the normal distribution. So, if the true distribution is normal, we can expect that the correlation would be high.

Comment: So .... let me check check and see if my interpretation is correct..... The "Shapiro Wilk" test is basically the measure of correlation for the Q-Q plot?

Comment: It's similar to it, but isn't actually that correlation. The Shapiro-Francia test is effectively that sort of correlation.